# How can I speed this tesseract OCR read of YouTube up? c#

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to read YouTube for certain text using tesseract-ocr in C#.

I'd like to make this process as quick as possible.

This is how I've currently implemented it.

```
    if(engine == null) engine = new TesseractEngine(@"./tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.Default);

    engine.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz0123456789"); // If digit on

    using (var img = PixConverter.ToPix(Bmp))
    {

        using (var page = engine.Process(img))
        {
            string HOCRXML = page.GetHOCRText(1);
            return HOCRXML;
        }
    }
```

I've tried IronOCR but it seems to perform at a similar speed.

What options are available to me to make this Tesseract implementation faster?

Comment: Better hardware? Faster internet?

Comment: Well, do an investigation: Does TesseractOCR utilize all cores in your system? If not, if it is being single-threaded, can several images OCR'ed in parallel without Tesseract stumbling and falling on its face? (Try it and see what happens and how fast it performs.)